# Prove that $\int_EM_{F,\lambda}f(x)dx<\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let compact set $E \subset (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\lambda >0$. Consider the integral

$$M_{F,\lambda}f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\delta_E^\lambda(y)f(y)}{|x-y|^{1+\lambda}}dy.$$

Where $\delta_E(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,E)$ and $f$ a nonnegative function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}$\ $E)$

Prove that:

$$\int_EM_{F,\lambda}f(x)dx<\infty.$$

I have tried using Fubini's theorem and convolution inequality for integrals to bound the integral but had no luck until now.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for making an informative title.